Proper way to include source files in CMake library with multiple dirs
I'm new to CMake and I have a c++ project that I'm trying to put together using cmake, much of the code exists already with classes in nested dirs.  I am able to get it all to compile with something like this
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    ./nested/folder/with/source.cc
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    "."
    "./nested/folder/with/"

My question is should I list out the dir structure like that? I only find examples of dirs one level down.
I feel like I could use 'glob' but couldn't get that to work or let cmake traverse the dirs and include the files down at the lowest level, but I couldn't get that to work either.  Any suggestions or an example would be great!

I typically create CMakeLists.txt files for every sub-directory, and then use the add_subdirectory command to use them.

There is nothing inherently wrong with passing path longer than one level in target_include_directories (unless that is because you have messed up project structure and are trying to work around it with CMake). Presumably the examples you saw focused on making it simple?

The developers of CMake at one point recommended against using glob so I have avoided it for most of my code however I do use it for test applications. One problem with glob is if you add additional files you have to execute CMake to regenerate for them to be considered. Although with that said glob doesn't solve any problem you can't solve by typing. And in either case CMake does not force you into any type of directory structure at all. It's all of personal choice.

For me every target has at least 1 CMakeLists.txt and all folders from a target to the root have CMakeLists.txt files. I may have more than 1 CMakeLists.txt for a target if the target has a logical way to split the files and it didn't warrant creating additional libraries.

Also, you don't need target_include_directories unless you have header files in your nested structure you want to #include without a relative path (which I would prefer).

@drescherjm they still don't recommend globs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem
